# В каком слове на месте пропуска пишется буква Е?

Tags: орфография

В каком слове на месте пропуска пишется буква ***е***?

1. прин  вший;
2. подч  вать;
3. кле  щий (обои);
4. выстел ть;
5. ма щийся.

   Я расставила так:

1 прин**я**вший,2 подч**и**вать,3 кле**я**щий,4 выстел**и**ть,5 ма**ю**щийся.

Насчет *"подчивать"* не уверена есть ли вообще такое слово. Знаю что есть *"потчевать"*. У меня получается что ни в одном слове нет **е**.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Действительно, существует слово "потчевать" с буквой Е.

**ПОТЧЕВАТЬ**, кого. Разг. 1. Угощать (обычно усердно).  2. Предлагать чьему-л. вниманию (обычно в изобилии). Журнал потчует читателей стихами.

Очевидно, в задании ошибка или опечатка.